# Epub.js reader Highlight and Annotation

Tags: php, jquery, epub

I want to create functionality for highlight and Add tags using epub.js.

Need to give more that 6 colors for highlight.

Is this possible using epub.js??

Comment: I'm interested in this, too. Documentation is poor. I know about hypotes.is and  demo site http://futurepress.github.io/epub.js/examples/hypothesis.html#epubcfi(/6/12[xepigraph_001]!4/2/6/4/1:2) , but that's all! Here they say epub.js could also work locally: https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/issues/98